# onsubmit return validateForm isn't triggering

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, scope

This is really throwing me for a loop.
I had this form successfully validating with my javascript by calling `onsubmit="return validateForm()"` when my `validateForm` function was inside a global variable. Unfortunately, once I started trying to debug IE8, I kept getting errors for having a global variable and I decided to make it a global function instead...

Now I can't seem to get it to trigger at all. -_-

(And yeah—I've actually prefixed it in testing to make sure it wasn't conflicting due to being global.)

From what I can tell, I'm doing the epitome of a basic form. This method is the one shown on w3schools, and it works for them, so... what gives?

My form:

```
<form name="emailus" id="emailus" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
    <a href="mailto:example@email.com">
        <h3><i class="icon-envelope-alt icon-large"></i>Send us an email<span>: example@email.com</span></h3>
    </a>

    <div class="half">
        <fieldset class="name">
            <label for="cf_name">Name <span>*</span></label>
            <input type="text" id="cf_name" name="cf_name" class="textualformfield" placeholder="Jane Doe" pattern="^[a-zA-Z'\s]+$">
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="emailaddress">
            <label for="cf_email">E-mail <span>*</span></label>
            <input type="text" id="cf_email" name="cf_email" class="textualformfield" placeholder="janedoe@email.com" pattern="[a-z0-9!#$%\x26'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%\x26'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+(?:[A-Z]{2}|com|org|net|edu|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|asia|jobs|museum)\b">
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="phonenumber">
            <label for="cf_phonenumber">Phone</label>
            <input type="tel" id="cf_phonenumber" name="cf_phonenumber" class="textualformfield" placeholder="555-555-5555">
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="eventdate">
            <label for="cf_eventdate">Event Date</label>
            <input type="text" id="cf_eventdate" name="cf_eventdate" class="textualformfield" placeholder="May 25th, 2012">
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="location">
            <label for="cf_location">Location</label>
            <input type="text" id="cf_location" name="cf_location" class="textualformfield" placeholder="The Church">
        </fieldset>
    </div>

    <div class="half">
        <textarea name="cf_message" class="textualformfield" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

My javascript function, located outside of `(document).ready` so that it *should* be able to be called:

```
function validateForm() {
    window.alert("I'm activating!");
    var valid = true;

    jQuery('p.validationhelpers').remove();

    if (document.emailus.cf_email.value === '') {
        jQuery('.emailaddress').append("<p class='validationhelpers'>Please enter an email address.</p>");
        jQuery('.emailaddress>input').focus();
        valid = false;
    }

    if (document.emailus.cf_name.value === '') {
        jQuery('.name').append("<p class='validationhelpers'>Please enter your name.</p>");
        jQuery('.name>input').focus();
        valid = false;
    }

    return valid;
}
```

Instead, it just submits...
I feel like this is a dumb problem. I've tried replacing the `onsubmit`'s content with `return validateForm();`, `return false; return validateForm()` (which indeed returned false and prevented submission), `return validateForm(); return false();`, and `validateForm()` and `validateForm();`.

>_<

**SOLUTION:** bjornarvh found the real cause from debugging the actual site. I'm highlighting it here because the real answer is **within the comments** of the answer marked as Solved.

Turns out I was missing a closing bracket for one of my functions in javascript, which was causing the `validateForm` function to be wrapped within `(document).ready`, which made it inaccessible to `onsubmit`. Accidental scope issue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript is case sensitive, so you need to add

```
onsubmit="return ValidateForm()"
```

instead of

```
onsubmit="return validateForm()"
```

Comment: Ah, crap. I'm sorry—I messed up copy/pasting because I removed the prefix for the posted example. The actual code doesn't have that issue, though. The cases are identical.

Comment: I tried the code locally and it seems to work as expected. I could try to debug your site, but I get a "Womp Womp. We probably almost certainly broke this page. Help us out real quick?" when I go to "Contact" @aminimalanimal

Comment: It shouldn't let you go to contact at all. Clicking Contact from /info should overlay the form atop the current page... If that's what you're doing and it's letting you click through to /contact, what browser are you in? @bjornarvh

Comment: @aminimalanimal Tried it in Opera, Chrome and IE10

Comment: O_o Okay, a few minutes ago, I added a closing bracket that IE8 told me I needed (for which I cannot find any need for whatsoever), and then tested clicking Contact in Chrome (Mac), Safari, Firefox, and IE8 (Windows XP VirtualBox). All showed the contact form overlay successfully... so unless lacking that bracket is what broke it for you, I've got no idea what's going on there. Try one more time in any of them?

Comment: @aminimalanimal Working now. From what I can see the } you have marked as ending the whenReady() is in fact ending the pageThresholdReloader(). If you add the ending } to that function, I think it should work.